# PHP multiple file upload: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, file-upload

i'm following this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/comment-page-1/#comments to learn how to upload multiple files via ajax.

This is my html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="settingsChangeAvatar" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $AJAX."/ajaxUpload.php"?>">
    <input class="input-xlarge input-file" id="settingsUploadAvatar" name="settingsUploadAvatar" type="file" multiple />
    <button class="btn" id="uploadAvatarButton" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

And this is my ajaxUpload.php:

```
foreach($_FILES["settingsUploadAvatar"]["error"] as $key => $error){
    if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $name = $_FILES["settingsUploadAvatar"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["settingsUploadAvatar"]["tmp_name"][$key], $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/webname/".$_FILES["settingsUploadAvatar"]["name"][$key]);
    }
}

echo("File uploaded");
```

My code should be the same as the one in the tutorial.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Did you simply `var_dump($_FILES)` to see what's in there? Basic debugging is in order here...

Comment: First thing I notice is you're missing `[]` on the end of the input's name attr:  `name='settingsUploadAvatar[]`

Comment: whoever gave this post a -1 clearly has no interest in actually being helpful. the question is clearly defined, take a peek at the title: "PHP multiple file upload: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". +1. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the 'name' attribute of your input from `settingsUploadAvatar` to `settingsUploadAvatar[]`.